# Как изменить ярлыки на графике в гугл таблице?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Можно ли изменить вид ярлыков на графике гугл-таблицы? В ecxel есть разные варианты изображения ярлыков. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, можно. Настройка аналогична Excel.

Чтобы изменить параметры всей серии точек, выделяем график, выбираем из его меню (три точки в правом верхнем углу) пункт "Edit chart", затем вкладку "Customize" и секцию "Series".

Чтобы изменить внешний вид отдельных точек серии, выделяем эти точки и правой кнопкой мыши вызываем контекстное меню, в котором выбираем "Format Data Point" (показано ниже на рисунке).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]